# Child aar content is omitted

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, aar

I'm building an aar library for android, which in it's turn, includes another aar, build on third one.
Looks like this AAR1(AAR2(AAR3)).
The resulting AAR1 just doesn't contain any classes or resources of AAR2(...) while they are used during compile step [AAR1 uses some classes from AAR2].
It's really wierd, cuz it has the same settings as AAR2, which completely consumes all content from AAR3.
How can I enable some verbose mode and what should I look for in Gradle console to debug the problem?

Comment: The purpose of building AAR1 over AAR2 is to provide abstraction over AAR2's implementation. As long as the AAR1 is built correctly, it would consume AAR2's methods that were needed for its implementation. Same would be the case between AAR2 and AAR3. Any specific reason you would want AAR1 to provide features of AAR2 and AAR3?. If you still want to do that, then you will have to implement wrapper methods in AAR1 that invoke AAR2 and AAR3.

Comment: I do it because I have 3 different libs, dependent one from another. I add them to the project relaying on the value of functionality I need. So instead of adding AAR1 and AAR2, I just add AAR2, and so on. I know it's against the very library idea) But the main point still remains the same: I want to deal with build process.